# Hide existing Chrome/Firefox autofill dropdown through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, autocomplete, autofill

I would like to hide the Chrome autofill dropdown when user hovers on my topbar menus, because the menu dropdown appears below the autofill dropdown.

The scenario is:

1. user clicks the input box, the autofill dropdown appears.
2. user moves mouse to topbar menu, menu dropdown appears, **but it is below the autofill dropdown**
3. So, i want to hide the autofill dropdown through JS when user moves mouse to my topbar menu.

### Trial 1

Disable the autofill temporarily, and enable it when user move mouse out of the topbar menu.

```
$('.menu-dropdown').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});
```

Althought it disables the autofill, the existing autofill dropdown does not hide immediately. I need to click somewhere else to hide it. After that, the autofill is disabled.

### Trial 2

Trigger click event on some other element (use the real mouse, click any where on the page will hide the autofill dropdown):

```
$('.menu-dropdown').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('#someOtherElement').click();
});
```

It is not working.

### Trial 3

Trigger the `ESC` event:

```
var esc = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 27 });
$('.menu-dropdown').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $("body").trigger(esc);
});
```

Not working as well.

Please kindly help. Thanks.

---

### Solution

Thanks to @Focki, here is the solution: disable the input autofill initially, only enable it when focused. When blured, disable it again.

```
// For Firefox: use `removeAttr`, instead of `attr('autocomplete', 'off'), 
$('input').removeAttr('autocomplete').focus(function() {      
  $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'on'); 
}).blur(function() {    
  $(this).removeAttr('autocomplete'); 
});

// Important: When user moves mouse to the topbar dropdown, trigger the blur event on input
$('.dropdown').on('mouseenter', function () {
  $('input').trigger('blur');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried 1 and 2 combined?

Comment: Thanks @Focki. It does not work :(

Comment: Mhh. Maybe vice versa? Set the Input´s autocomplete to off by default and enable it onfocus

Comment: Seems promising. Let me try it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Focki. Your approach works. Please anwser below. I will mark it as the correct answer. Hopefully can help other developers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisting the order can work on this issue.
Set the Input´s autocomplete to off by default and enable it onfocus

```
$('input').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'on');
});
```

Comment: I updated my answer to include my solution specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I hope changing the id of datalist will help for example in this code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input id="" type="submit">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").on("input",function(){
        $('datalist').attr('id','sometext'); //add this line of code
// and you can change id back to original state when you want to turn on autocompletion...
    });``
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

may be this will help you...

Comment: i know this code is inefficient... just wrote to explain what i wanted to explain...

Comment: This works too. And it is an interesting solution (kindof hack). Thanks @Sanjeev Prasad Thakur.

Comment: I am new to this site and i am happy, that i found myself helpful to you...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You will enjoy it. I updated my answer to include my solution specifically. Your solution has a side-effect, changing the id may break other code referring to this input box.

Comment: yes it has... but you can provide some garbage id... that is not identical to any other id... and later it can be retrieved using that garbage id...instead of using... $('input').attr(id,somenewid)... we can use as...
$('#someid').attr(id,garbageid);

and later we can retrieve it using;

$("#garbageid").attr('id','originalId');

and i think this will be an interesting... solution...

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you turn of the autocomplete for the input and form tag(If your input tag is in the form). Also, you don't have to set the attribute when the user puts there mouse in the form. Instead, just set the attribute in the HTML itself. If you must do it with Jquery, Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    $('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});
```

Pure Javascript:

```
document.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("input").setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
    document.getElementsByTagName("form").setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Rishi. I think you misunderstood my question. I do not want to disable the autofill. I want to hide the autofill dropdown temporarily when user hovers on my topbar menus. The scenario is: 1. user clicks the input box, the autofill dropdown appears. 2. user moves mouse to topbar menu, menu dropdown appears, but it is below the autofill dropdown 3. So, i want to hide the autofill dropdown through JS.

Comment: Use autocomplete="nope". Here, Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion. You can change $('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off'); to $('input').attr('autocomplete', 'nope');